# I get logged out automatically after a few seconds of logging in (Desktop)

Tags: 16.04, login, lightdm

I get logged out (not locked out) of my desktop session after logging in on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I see the following on `/var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log`

> ```
> > [+0.59s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User108 added [+0.59s]
> > DEBUG: Connected to Application Indicator Service. [+0.63s] DEBUG:
> > menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object 0xc05400 at position 0
> > [+0.66s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object 0xc05560 at
> > position 1 [+0.69s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object
> > 0xc05820 at position 2 [+0.70s] DEBUG: Request current apps [+0.71s]
> > DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object 0xc052a0 at position
> > 3 [+0.77s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:240: starting system-ready sound
> > [+0.78s] DEBUG: background.vala:121: Render of background
> > /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png complete
> > 
> > ** (unity-settings-daemon:7535): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such
> > method 'RegisterClient'
> > 
> > (unity-settings-daemon:7535): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to get
> > edid: unable to get EDID for output
> > 
> > (nm-applet:7490): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer
> > in cast to 'GtkWidget'
> > 
> > (nm-applet:7490): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion
> > 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
> > 
> > (unity-settings-daemon:7535): color-plugin-WARNING **: unable to get
> > EDID for xrandr-Virtual1: unable to get EDID for output [+0.95s]
> > DEBUG: Building new application entry: :1.18  with icon:
> > nm-device-wired at position 0 [+0.96s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding
> > indicator object 0xb76a00 at position 4
> ```

`/var/lightdm/lightdm.log` shows the following right after I log in:

```
[+644.03s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+644.04s] DEBUG: Session pid=7473: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+644.04s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user user: Success
[+644.04s] DEBUG: User user authorized
[+644.04s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session ubuntu
[+644.04s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping greeter; display server will be re-used for user session
[+644.04s] DEBUG: Session pid=7425: Sending SIGTERM
[+644.07s] DEBUG: Session pid=7425: Exited with return value 0
[+644.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+644.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Greeter stopped, running session
[+644.07s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session3
[+644.07s] DEBUG: Session pid=7473: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
[+644.07s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/user
[+644.07s] DEBUG: Session pid=7473: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+644.11s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+644.11s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c13
[+644.11s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c13
[+644.11s] DEBUG: Session c13 is already active
```

And then when it logs me out:

```
[+666.61s] DEBUG: Session pid=7473: Exited with return value 0
[+666.61s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+666.61s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+666.61s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 7420
[+666.61s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to
[+666.62s] CRITICAL: session_get_login1_session_id: assertion 'session != NULL' failed
[+666.97s] DEBUG: Process 7420 exited with return value 0
[+666.97s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: X server stopped
[+666.97s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+666.97s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+666.97s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+666.97s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Active display server stopped, starting greeter
[+666.97s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+666.97s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+666.97s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+666.97s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+666.97s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+666.97s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+666.97s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Launching X Server
[+666.97s] DEBUG: Launching process 8272: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+666.97s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+667.12s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 8272
[+667.12s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Got signal from X server :0
[+667.12s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+667.12s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+667.12s] DEBUG: Session pid=8277: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+667.13s] DEBUG: Session pid=8277: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+667.13s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+667.13s] DEBUG: Session pid=8277: Running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
[+667.13s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/lightdm
[+667.13s] DEBUG: Session pid=8277: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log
[+667.16s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+667.16s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c14
[+667.16s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c14
[+667.16s] DEBUG: Session c14 is already active
[+667.26s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.18.2 resettable=false
[+667.32s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for user
[+667.32s] DEBUG: Session pid=8325: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'user'
[+667.32s] DEBUG: Session pid=8325: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+667.32s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+667.38s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User108 added
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you likely don't have enough video RAM.  I ran into the same error on VirtualBox with only 32MB of VRAM configured.  When I configured the VRAM to have more memory the issue was resolved (in my case I made it 128MB).

Comment: Looks promising, but I have the video ram set to 1024MB. This was working fine until I had a power outage and the VM host machine got shut down improperly. I think a file might have gotten corrupted